# Java keytool doesn't like OpenSSL CSR

Tags: java, keytool, self-signed, jks

I'm trying to use OpenSSL to create a self-signed SSL certificate and then add that certificate to a JKS file (Java keystore) so I can have a Jetty-based web service serve that self-signed certificate to HTTP clients over HTTPS.

I created the OpenSSL self-signed cert:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout mykey-dev.pem -out mycsr-dev.pem -days 3650
```

I then created the JKS:

```
keytool -alias myorg -keyalg RSA -keystore myapp.jks -keysize 2048
```

I *believe* I now need to import the CSR (`mycsr-dev.pem`) into the JKS:

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file mycsr-dev.pem -alias myorg -keystore myapp.jks
```

This produces the following error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match
```

**Any idea what the problem is?**

Comment: well, you created a keypair with -genkey and then you're imported an unrelated key into the same alias. Skip the genkey step.

Comment: thanks @JamesKPolk (+1) - please see my edit above...is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: Just skip the entire command.

Comment: That worked @JamesKPolk (+1) - if you care to, if you add a simple 1-liner answer below explaining why that 2nd command was unnecessary + problematic, I'll happily give you the green check!

Comment: (1) You created a key and cert not a CSR; they are different things. `openssl req -new` alone creates a CSR, which cannot be used as a cert; `openssl req -new -x509` creates a cert, which is not a CSR. (2) You don't need OpenSSL at all; just `keytool -genkey[pair]` (which you wrongly remved from your Q) generates a key AND A SELF-SIGNED CERT automatically. For TLS server, specify FQDN to the 'first and last name' prompt, or use `-dname CN=FQDN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because `keytool genkey -alias myorg ...` created a keypair and the `openssl req` command also creates an unrelated keypair. Trying to import the cert from the `openssl req` command into the JKS keystore under the `myorg` alias therefore causes a conflict between the two different public keys. If you intend to import a trusted certificate into the keystore then simply do the import under the desired alias, there is no need to create the alias ahead of time with `keytool genkey ...`.

Comment: OP wants a server, which requires a key AND cert in a Java PrivateKeyEntry, NOT a trusted cert.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That is not clear from the question.

Comment: Thanks @JamesKPolk (+1) - just curious, is `mycsr-dev.pem` the "public key" and `mykey-dev.pem` the "private key"?

Comment: `mycsr-dev.pem` is a certificate containing the public key, and `mykey-dev.pem` is the private key.

Answer (score 1):

openssl create PEM format file, while keytool will jks format.

this is how to convert certificate from pem to jks:

cat cert_public_key.pem cert_private_key.pem | openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.p12

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cert.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore cert.jks

Comment: Actually keytool, and JCE and many Java programs including Jetty, supports both JKS and PKCS12. Through j8 it _defaults_ to JKS but j9 changes the default to PKCS12.